# Can't call next() as last piece of middleware?

Tags: node.js, express

For some reason, if I'm the last piece of middleware and I try calling the `next()` function, I get the same error as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7042340/3813411) common SO issue.

So that I have a minimal example, I set it up as follows:

In my route, I have:

```
router.get('/add',(req,res,next) => {
    res.render('ideas/add');
    next();
});
```

And then I have a final piece of middleware:

```
app.use(function finalMiddleware(req,res,next){
    console.log("We are here!");
    console.log(app._router.stack);
    next();
});
```

And the console logs the following as the last element in the stack:

```
  Layer {
    handle: [Function: finalMiddleware],
    name: 'finalMiddleware',
    params: {},
    path: '',
    keys: [],
    regexp: { /^\/?(?=\/|$)/i fast_star: false, fast_slash: true },
    route: undefined } ]
```

However, I still get:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:471:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (../node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (../node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at done (../node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1004:10)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (../node_modules/express-handlebars/lib/utils.js:26:13)
```

I'm wondering if this for some reason has to do with handlebars? I just don't understand why if I'm not writing headers with later middleware that this would possibly be an issue. I can't seem to figure out how to debug it further. Sure, I can remove the `next()` call from my final piece of middleware, but I want to understand if there's something deeper going on as I'm new to Express and want to make I'm understanding stuff correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/7042340/3461055

Comment: @ArifKhan no, I linked that in my description.

Comment: Please read carefully, issue is same, `res.render` finished the response, you can not call next or another middleware after `res.render`

Comment: @ArifKhan, you're right. Sorry, I didn't understand at first. I figured it out. Does middlware that's not in a router callback, when calling `next()` will send a `Cannot GET` message also? Or is it just if it's called in a router callback?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was missing a key piece of information from both the similar answer and from my investigation: if `next()` is called and nothing is left to execute in regards to middlware, the server will send a message `Cannot GET /(route name)`. For me, my callback was executing after this message was sent, since `next()` must call the function that writes this default response.

Hence, since Express already sent the message `Cannot GET /(routename)`, as soon as the callback fired, which was after, it wasn't able to send a response.